# How to write a iostream binary in the exact same format as CStdioFile would?

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to write data in a binary format.

I have this function currently that works with the `CStdioFile` class in Visual Studio:

```cpp
CStdioFile data(_this->output_dir + L"\\" + saveFileName + ".binary", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::typeBinary | CFile::modeReadWrite);
//some code
data.Write(&x, 4);
data.Write(&y, 4);
data.flush();
data.close();
```

But this class is not available on Linux, and I'm struggling to make my code create the exact same output that `CStdioFile` would create using `fstream` or any other Linux-compatible library.

This is the code I'm trying to use to write the same `&x` and `&y` data with `fstream`, but the output file is different:

```cpp
fstream data(of + "\\" + saveFileName + ".binary", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
data.write((const char*)&x, sizeof(float));
data.write((const char*)&y, sizeof(float));
data.close();
```

With `CStdioFile` I get as an output a hex-encoded binary file with columns of 4 characters

```
bc68 b44a 3d82 7d4f 70af 524a 0aba 174f
d84f f349 3e07 af4e f0f7 8c49 6c4c 484e
80d9 7a48 acab 384d 2855 ac4a bae3 724f
(...)
```

With the `iostream` output, I get this instead:

```
NìF’HU‹uMž½JÈI˜OÉÝ^Jnã8Ou2ýIjËN^WIÄ¥hNVH²HÿiˆM6IõuÈN‰(I)¹N ™¡HÚù1NŸ]DH¸CØM€ÿnGÈ›MLu)I\¡ºNÁPI¶u¯NÞ…H„NÕðQH7çM(¨gGÇ!ÿLèì¦HÀ&ÜNôšHšØËNÈ3H=uCNÚ´GèíMÜ.ÛF6‰M˜h›H\öÌN\’HÓ±ÀNxöôG0‰!NîˆÀG:íýMPsÔF¨MàöHò‘NðïùG¢\†Nð¦oG:Õ NÀšG”ŒœM`71Fx‰¾L@NûGü‡N CìGà~NpFG”òÔM «G"_§MðÅ+F4¯¸L`[G`znN@½„GÂÐ\N(...)
```

Comment: Whose `CStdioFile` class are you using?

Comment: And how is this related to the CSV tag?  Is that class so broken that it creates a delimited text file when you ask it for binary?

Comment: @JaMiT looks like a different format for the output. CStdioFile has a hex representation of binary as output, and the fstream one just the characters

Comment: I have this function currently that works with the CStdioFile class on Visual Studio

Comment: @EdisAhmethodzic -- *With the CStdioFile I get as an output an hex encoded binary file with columns of 4 characters* -- You get *columns* in a binary file?   Try your Linux code under Windows without using CStdioFile -- what results do you get then? (Honestly, that should have been the first thing you needed to try)

Comment: The MFC classes use *serialization* to write out their data to files in a custom format. `fstream` does not do that (unless you use the `operator<<`, but that is not the same format). Your `fstream` code is simply writing out the raw bytes of your variables as-is.  If you want your code to be compatible with files created by MFC, you will have to duplicate MFC's serialization logic in your own code.  Otherwise, forget MFC's format and just save your files in your own format.

Comment: @steps My question was directed at the person who asked the question, and it was asked before that person added the relevant information to the question. Are you the self-appointed arbiter of this question? (I notice you had edited the question for "improved clarity" by apparently guessing at missing information, e.g. "Linux".)